# How Do I Apply to Become a Marketplace Creator?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So I wanted to make some minecoins and I also heard that anyone become a marketplace creator could but I don't know where to apply. I'm in Minecraft Pocket Edition 1.14.30. Can you tell me where I can apply?

Answer (score 4):

You must be part of the [Minecraft Partner Program](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/partner). On this page, you can apply.

Keep in mind that demand to be a partner is very high; it is common to have to wait several months to even hear a reply. You also must show that you have the skills to create content, such as a portfolio of existing creations (worlds, skins, etc.) that you have personally created.

Comment: Says Access restricted

Comment: Anybody have any update on this? Is there a support ticket with Microsoft? Do they even have any idea that creator registration is broken?

Comment: Looks like they just moved the URL. I've updated it to the right location.